# can we pass the username in videocore library for RTMP URL?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, wowza, broadcasting, videocore

I am making an app based on broadcasting I am using videoCore Lib for Broadcast for that I am using below code to start rtmp session

```
  [_session startRtmpSessionWithURL:urlForStream
                                     andStreamKey:streamID];
```

urlForStream is url of wowza server like rtmp://some.tv/some/username/username/randamvalue
that Randam value is don't want to override my videos every time  so i am using that url and now My Problem is VCSessionState class state is not changing it is not coming to started state and I am getting the Error here is streamsessio.mm class  and [NSRL(m_runLoop) run]; i don't kow where i miss please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Considering from my experience of having created my own RTMP protocol library, I thought you have to separate the URL into two parts: tcUrl and stream key. In your case, the random value is likely to be a stream key.

```
NSString *tcUrl;
NSString *stream;
separateRtmpUrl(urlForStream, &tcUrl, &stream);
[_session startRtmpSessionWithURL:tcUrl andStreamKey:stream];
```

The definition of the `separateRtmpUrl` function can be like this.

```
static void separateRtmpUrl(NSString *baseUrl, NSString **tcUrl, NSString **stream)
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl];
    *stream = url.pathComponents.lastObject;
    *tcUrl  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@%@", url.scheme, url.host,
               [NSString pathWithComponents:
                [url.pathComponents subarrayWithRange:
                 NSMakeRange(0, url.pathComponents.count - 1)]]];

    if (url.query) {
        *stream = [@[*stream , url.query] componentsJoinedByString:@"?"];
        *tcUrl  = [@[*tcUrl  , url.query] componentsJoinedByString:@"?"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay i use above code still i am unable to start the session and i am not getting any error its simply disconnect

Comment: that randam value is getting from my server then i will add to rtmp url but i don't know where i miss it is calling the connectionStatusChanged delegate method but not in case of VCSessionStateStarted

Comment: @Bittoo Sorry, I'm familiar with the RTMP protocol itself, but not with Wowza and the library you are using.

Comment: But still, I think it's needed to give a stream key instead of an empty string to `startRtmpSessionWithURL `, getting it from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks@ findall also tried the stream key with some value but no use Thanks for your responce